# Lucene.net how to order and query KeyValuePair data type

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to find a solution about indexing-querying following model:
Student has many Lessons and for each Lesson there is one grade. However Lesson-Grade is a key value pair.

**my first question is :**

> how should i index in lucene that keyvalue data? (its like a
>   coordinate may be spatial?)

**second one is**

> Assume i have a indexed data in lucene. How can i query Students, by
>   Lesson name but ordered by Grade.

```
Student | Lesson    | Grade
----------------------------
John    | Math      | A
John    | Chemistry | C
Julie   | Math      | F
Julie   | Chemistry | A
```

can i create a query something similar 'select from student where Lesson = Math order by Grade' sql phrase

Answer (score 2):

In Lucene, you index documents in indexes, documents have fields.

In your case, you would have a Document with 3 fields: Student, Lesson and Grade. You then populate an index with these documents.

Small example:

```cs
RAMDirectory ramDir = new RAMDirectory();

IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(ramDir, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));


Document doc = new Document();
Field studentName = new Field("student", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
Field lesson = new Field("lesson", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
Field grade = new Field("grade","", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);

doc.Add(studentName);
doc.Add(lesson);
doc.Add(grade);

studentName.SetValue("John");
lesson.SetValue("Math");
grade.SetValue("A");
writer.AddDocument(doc);

studentName.SetValue("John");
lesson.SetValue("Chemistry");
grade.SetValue("C");
writer.AddDocument(doc);

studentName.SetValue("Julie");
lesson.SetValue("Math");
grade.SetValue("F");
writer.AddDocument(doc);

studentName.SetValue("Julie");
lesson.SetValue("Chemistry");
grade.SetValue("A");
writer.AddDocument(doc);

writer.Commit();
IndexReader reader = writer.GetReader();
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper aw = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
aw.AddAnalyzer("grade", new KeywordAnalyzer());
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("grade", SortField.STRING));

QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "lesson", aw);

Query q = qp.Parse("chemistry");

TopDocs docs = searcher.Search(q, null, 100, sort);

foreach (var scoreDoc in docs.ScoreDocs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Student: {0}; Lesson: {1}; Grade:{2}", 
        searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc).GetField("student").StringValue(),
        searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc).GetField("lesson").StringValue(),
        searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc).GetField("grade").StringValue());
}

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("---");
Console.WriteLine("");

q = qp.Parse("Math");

docs = searcher.Search(q, null, 100, sort);

foreach (var scoreDoc in docs.ScoreDocs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Student: {0}; Lesson: {1}; Grade:{2}",
        searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc).GetField("student").StringValue(),
        searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc).GetField("lesson").StringValue(),
        searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc).GetField("grade").StringValue());
}

Console.Read();

reader.Close();
searcher.Close();
writer.Close();
```

prints:

```
Student: Julie; Lesson: Chemistry; Grade:A
Student: John; Lesson: Chemistry; Grade:C

---

Student: John; Lesson: Math; Grade:A
Student: Julie; Lesson: Math; Grade:F
```